# How to redirect HTTP to HTTPS on Akamai?

Tags: http, redirect, https, akamai

I'm trying to redirect HTTP to HTTPS on Akamai but it says...

> Enhanced Akamai Protocol is not compatible with Request Protocol and
>   cannot be used with a rule using this match.

It also says...

> Caution! You should not remove the Enhanced Akamai Protocol without an
>   extremely good reason to do so.

How can I implement the redirect with Enhanced Akamai Protocol enabled?

[image: Akamai screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you are using a wrong behavior. user redirect behavior, you will have option to set either 301 or 302 etc.